# Prehung Door Frame's Latch Hole

Tags: doors, prehung

I purchased some prehung interior doors. Is there a standard way to fill/cover the back of the frame's latch hole? I'd prefer if there wasn't a hole exposing the cavity between the frame and wall.

[image]

Comment: Have you compared the length of the latch bolt to the thickness of the casing? You might need some space beyond the casing.

Comment: The latch bolt does not extend past the frame. But do most people just leave the latch cut-out open in the frame as-is? Seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

There are strike plates which include a dust box behind them; you could get one of those rather than using the one that comes with the lockset.

Even better, as long as you're paying a few dollars to upgrade, consider a high-security strike. These come with hardware that secures them to the doorway's framing studs, not just the relatively thin wood enclosing the doorway itself, and significantly increase the door's strength. And they usually include a dust box of the sort I mentioned above.